# Laravel calling model with variable in controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am using one function in controller for inserting in several different tables with different Models. I mean that in controller model is variable.

This code bellow works perfectly but i don't like syntax, i am pretty sure there must be some other ways than `str_replace` for calling model with `\App\` in front of it's name.

Calling only by Model name without `\App\` causes laravel error `Class not found`.  I have written `use \App\ModelName` in controller's file but it still does't works.

```
public function storeCommon(Request $request){
   $model = '"\App\"'. $request->model;
   $model =  str_replace ( "\"", "", $model ) ;

   ........
   ........       

   $row['text'] = $request->text;
   ........
   ........
   $common = $model::create($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather define array of possible models and use it within the code. This way you **will protect your code** against call for unwanted models and off course your code will be much readable:

```
protected $possibleModels = [
    'Model1' => \App\Model1::class,
    'Model2' => \App\Model2::class,
    ...
    ];

public function storeCommon(Request $request){
    if (!isset($this->possibleModels[$request->model])) {
        abort(404);
    }
    $model = $this->possibleModels[$request->model];
    $row['text'] = $request->text;
    ...
    $common = $model::create($row);
}
```

Comment: Hi, was thinking about it getting model by variable from array because of this syntax problems, than i thought that there was too much code for removing bad syntax. Now i realized that it would be more protective too, nice idea mate thanks for it :)